# Watching a movie and working with a laptop simultaneously

Tags: video, multiple-monitors, hdmi, lcd

I have an LCD TV and a laptop. I connected the laptop to the LCD by HDMI. Now I want to play a movie by a movie player like VLC. But when I play it, both the LCD TV and the laptop monitor show the movie. I want to watch the movie on the LCD TV and work with the laptop monitor simultaneously. How can I do this? My OS is Windows 8.

Comment: Not really a great way to work, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In display setting you can change the options to split screen instead of mirroring the display . Just check how to change the display settings it would be somewhere in properties when you right click you should see personalize options.

Comment: Why didn't I try it before? Thank you :)